# Opening New Console Application Window

Tags: c++

Using C/C++, I am trying, from a Console Application, to open another Console Application in a new Console window, and just let it run. Currently, all my attempts have ended up with the two applications sharing a window, which is not what I want.

I am currently using [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) however I can't work out which arguments I need to set. I've managed to show and hide the output, etc. etc., but it all still shows in the same window.

I've tried a few messy hacks involving **cmd.exe** and **start**, but I haven't managed to get them to work either.

Basically, I want to achieve this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/createnowindow.aspx

equivalent to `UseShellExecute` (true) and `CreateNoWindow` (false), but in C++.

Does anybody know how to do this? It seems as though it should be so simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try AllocConsole: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console.` He's trying to do it from a console app ;) EDIT: Though maybe it could be helpful anyway... Start the new process, FreeConsole, then AllocConsole. Seems a bit hacky but might work?

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help! I tried that FreeConsole - AllocConsole trick (neat idea!) but I couldn't get it to work. Might be just me, but it isn't as simple as it should be. Anyway, I've now discovered that the solution is really, really simple! I was looking at the STARTUPINFO structure, which was the wrong place to look. I should have looked at process creation flags - CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE. Works like a charm :)

Comment: You may also have been able to disable handle inheritance. Depending on what you needed, it might not have been what you wanted though (eg, it would also disable pipes).